# Root path with Nginx, Puma and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, dns, ubuntu-14.04, puma

I deployed my website on an Ubuntu 14.04 server with nginx and puma and it's working well as long as I use the IP adress to reach the site. I am trying to set up the domain at the moment and it's not working as it should.

This is how my nginx config looks like:

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/savoir/shared/tmp/sockets/savoir-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  server_name mydomain.de;

  root /home/deploy/apps/savoir/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/savoir/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/savoir/current/log/nginx.error.log debug;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

If I try to reach the site with my browser using the domain I get a blank page and the url changes to: `mydomain.de/defaultsite`. I would like to get the root page that I set up for my rails application.

EDIT:

nginx error log:

```
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 000000000077CE08, pos 000000000077CE08, size: 756 file: 0, size: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:756
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http cacheable: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http proxy filter init s:200 h:0 c:0 l:-1
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http upstream process upstream
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe read upstream: 1
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe preread: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 readv: 1:3441
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 readv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe recv chain: -2
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 000000000077BCD0, pos 000000000077BF5F, size: 0 file: 0, size: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe length: -1
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 event timer: 12, old: 1458299703835, new: 1458299703856
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 post event 00000000007A1178
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 post event 00000000007B4988
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 delete posted event 00000000007B4988
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http upstream request: "/?"
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http upstream dummy handler
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 delete posted event 00000000007A1178
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http upstream request: "/?"
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http upstream process upstream
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe read upstream: 1
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 readv: 1:3441
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe recv chain: 3441
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 input buf #0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 malloc: 000000000077DCF0:4096
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 readv: 1:4096
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe recv chain: 2843
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 readv: 1:1253
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 readv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe recv chain: -2
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe buf in   s:1 t:1 f:0 000000000077BCD0, pos 000000000077BF5F, size: 3441 file: 0, size: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 000000000077DCF0, pos 000000000077DCF0, size: 2843 file: 0, size: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe length: -1
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe write downstream: 1
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe write busy: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe write buf ls:1 000000000077BF5F 3441
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe write: out:000000000077D248, f:0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http output filter "/?"
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http copy filter: "/?"
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 image filter
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 xslt filter body
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http postpone filter "/?" 000000000077D248
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http gzip filter
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 malloc: 00007FDF6423B010:270336
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip alloc: n:1 s:5936 a:8192 p:00007FDF6423B010
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip alloc: n:32768 s:2 a:65536 p:00007FDF6423D010
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip alloc: n:32768 s:2 a:65536 p:00007FDF6424D010
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip alloc: n:32768 s:2 a:65536 p:00007FDF6425D010
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip alloc: n:16384 s:4 a:65536 p:00007FDF6426D010
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip in: 000000000077D330
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip in_buf:000000000077D1F8 ni:000000000077BF5F ai:3441
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 malloc: 00000000007C8060:4096
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 deflate in: ni:000000000077BF5F no:00000000007C8060 ai:3441 ao:4096 fl:0 redo:0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 deflate out: ni:000000000077CCD0 no:00000000007C8060 ai:0 ao:4096 rc:0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip in_buf:000000000077D1F8 pos:000000000077BF5F
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip in: 0000000000000000
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http copy filter: 0 "/?"
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe write busy: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe write: out:0000000000000000, f:0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe read upstream: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 000000000077DCF0, pos 000000000077DCF0, size: 2843 file: 0, size: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 000000000077BCD0, pos 000000000077BCD0, size: 0 file: 0, size: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe length: -1
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 event timer: 12, old: 1458299703835, new: 1458299703857
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 post event 00000000007A1178
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 post event 00000000007B4988
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 delete posted event 00000000007B4988
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http upstream request: "/?"
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http upstream dummy handler
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 delete posted event 00000000007A1178
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http upstream request: "/?"
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http upstream process upstream
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe read upstream: 1
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 readv: 2:4096
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe recv chain: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 000000000077DCF0, pos 000000000077DCF0, size: 2843 file: 0, size: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 000000000077BCD0, pos 000000000077BCD0, size: 0 file: 0, size: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe length: -1
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 input buf #1
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 free: 000000000077BCD0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe write downstream: 1
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe write downstream flush in
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http output filter "/?"
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http copy filter: "/?"
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 image filter
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 xslt filter body
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http postpone filter "/?" 000000000077D248
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http gzip filter
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip in: 000000000077D3B0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip in_buf:000000000077D1F8 ni:000000000077DCF0 ai:2843
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 deflate in: ni:000000000077DCF0 no:00000000007C8060 ai:2843 ao:4096 fl:0 redo:0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 deflate out: ni:000000000077E80B no:00000000007C8060 ai:0 ao:4096 rc:0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip in_buf:000000000077D1F8 pos:000000000077DCF0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip in: 0000000000000000
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http copy filter: 0 "/?"
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 pipe write downstream done
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 event timer: 12, old: 1458299703835, new: 1458299703857
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http upstream exit: 0000000000000000
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 finalize http upstream request: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 finalize http proxy request
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 free rr peer 1 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 close http upstream connection: 12
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 free: 000000000079F4B0, unused: 48
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 event timer del: 12: 1458299703835
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 reusable connection: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http upstream temp fd: -1
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http output filter "/?"
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http copy filter: "/?"
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 image filter
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 xslt filter body
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http postpone filter "/?" 00007FFE1A8B9110
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http gzip filter
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip in: 000000000077D410
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip in_buf:000000000077D3C0 ni:0000000000000000 ai:0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 deflate in: ni:0000000000000000 no:00000000007C8060 ai:0 ao:4096 fl:4 redo:0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 deflate out: ni:0000000000000000 no:00000000007C89BB ai:0 ao:1701 rc:1
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 gzip in_buf:000000000077D3C0 pos:0000000000000000
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 free: 00007FDF6423B010
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http chunk: 10
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http chunk: 2403
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 write old buf t:1 f:0 000000000077CE08, pos 000000000077CE08, size: 756 file: 0, size: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 000000000077D510, pos 000000000077D510, size: 5 file: 0, size: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 00000000006C9820, size: 10 file: 0, size: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 00000000007C8060, pos 00000000007C8060, size: 2403 file: 0, size: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 00000000004A1EB8, size: 7 file: 0, size: 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http write filter: l:1 f:1 s:3181
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http write filter limit 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 writev: 3181
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http write filter 0000000000000000
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http copy filter: 0 "/?"
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http finalize request: 0, "/?" a:1, c:1
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 set http keepalive handler
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http close request
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http log handler
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 free: 00000000007C8060
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 free: 0000000000000000
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 free: 000000000077DCF0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 free: 0000000000000000
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 free: 00000000007845B0, unused: 2
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 free: 000000000077ACC0, unused: 8
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 free: 000000000077CCE0, unused: 1625
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 free: 00000000007841A0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 hc free: 0000000000000000 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 tcp_nodelay
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 reusable connection: 1
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 event timer add: 11: 10000:1458299653857
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 post event 00000000007A1110
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 delete posted event 00000000007A1110
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http keepalive handler
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 malloc: 00000000007841A0:1024
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 recv: fd:11 -1 of 1024
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 epoll add event: fd:11 op:3 ev:80000005
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 free: 00000000007841A0
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 post event 00000000007B4920
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 delete posted event 00000000007B4920
2016/03/18 11:14:03 [debug] 60010#0: *1 http empty handler
```

nginx.access.log

```
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:14:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2425 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /list HTTP/1.1" 200 8800 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_4/image_9/thumb_regusse_2015_10_019.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_2/image_6/thumb_feb09_153.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_5/image_19/thumb_juli09_204.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_9/image_8/thumb_2015_okt_034.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_11/image_10/thumb_Jo_un_028_2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_12/image_11/thumb_mrz-apr2013_485.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_1/image_2/thumb_2015_oktober_038.JPG HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_8/image_3/thumb_2015_okt_015.JPG HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_7/image_12/thumb_januar2010_175.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_13/image_13/thumb_CIMG2137.JPG HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_15/image_15/thumb_IMG_1329.JPG HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_16/image_1/thumb_Ch%C3%AAnes-1.JPG HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_14/image_14/thumb_regusse_mai2011_043.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_17/image_27/thumb_151132_4_1_105649.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_18/image_16/thumb_IMG_7483.JPG HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_19/image_17/thumb_fayence_nov2010_014a.JPG HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_20/image_18/thumb_Barjols_054.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_21/image_26/thumb_101083-23-1-3-gr.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_6/image_4/thumb_Maison__Montbrun.JPG HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:29 +0000] "GET /uploads/picture/image/house_3/image_20/thumb_101083-8-1-2-gr.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://217.160.14.233/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:38 +0000] "GET /notes HTTP/1.1" 200 2542 "http://217.160.14.233/list" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:39 +0000] "GET /list HTTP/1.1" 200 8800 "http://217.160.14.233/notes" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
94.217.150.214 - - [18/Mar/2016:11:16:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2425 "http://217.160.14.233/list" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
```

EDIT:

Okay, I just realized that the command `host mydomain.de` returns another IP adress. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the domain `mydomain.de` points to your server? You can find out by running `host mydomain.de` (under unix/Linux). Did you update your DNS records recently? Maybe the only thing is to wait a little longer.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I used the command and it seems like the dns points to my server. I didn't update anything (only the nginx config).

Comment: OK, in that case, can you see your requests in nginx access log? Can you post some sample lines from this log?

Comment: Access log or error log? Trying to load the side using the domain name isn't giving me any error.

Comment: Ok and a part of the access log please? I'm trying to find out if your requests really land to the nginx. If they do, I wonder where does the 'defaultsite' redirect come from?

Comment: Did it but as I said it's not logging anything if I try to reach the site by domain.

Comment: Maybe check you haven't got `server_name mydomain.de;` defined in another config file such as `etc/nginx/sites-available/default` that is also been loaded?

Comment: Perhaps your requests get to the default nginx access log, which is usually at `/var/log/nginx/access.log`. This would prove @OddEssay's idea. You should check all sites defined in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and see if any of them does not use your domain too. Some more rather crazy ideas: what about some reverse proxy, or a router placed in front of your server that would diverge your requests?

Comment: Ok. @OddEssay I deleted the `etc/nginx/sites-available/default` so that can't be it I guess. Thanks for trying to help though. And the default access.log is not logging anything.

Comment: The server came with apache on it and I deinstalled it to use puma. Maybe something of the old setup is left and catches the request first?

Comment: Still haven't found a solution. If anyone has the slightest idea I would really appreciate it :)